# How to use HAProxy in load balancing and as a reverse proxy with docker?

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, linux-networking, haproxy, docker

I am using HAProxy docker image to load share between multiple similar containers. It's working fine if I am using a single address like `web.abc.com` to query only the API containers, which is mapped to my localhost . But now I want to use `api.abc.com` too with this HAProxy config file .

So the scenario is going to be if I hit `web.abc.com` it will share the load of web application  container using round robin and show me the contents of these containers and  if I  hit `api.abc.com` it gives me access of those containers which have the API  .

I have tried multiple config changes with my haproxy.cfg , but it's not working .

This is my docker-compose [file](http://pastebin.com/AtwA5eir), and this is the [haproxy.cfg](http://pastebin.com/5uG3eiy0) I am using , which is obviously not working

Is this scenario even possible with HAProxy ? Help me.

Comment: You should update your question to show the output of whatever tests you are carrying out that demonstrates "it's not working".

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen to generate HAProxy configuration on container start / stop.

You can take a look on the use of it in nginx + letsencrypt use case : https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion